# setven in launchd.conf on mac

Tags: macos, environment-variables, launchd

This is my first real development with the mac os(OS X 10.5.8).I got a macbookpro from work and i'm still setting up the right development environment.I've opted for the creation of /etc/launchd.conf and it's working fine for most of my librairies (JAVA_HOME, JRE_HOME)
i now need to add CATALINA_OPTS=-Duser.timezone=Asia/china but the syntax in mac for launchd.conf doesn't appear to have equal signe "=".all i've seen are spaces ,so i'm a bit lost when i need to add things like properties file or the one for tomcat.
i don't want to break anything and i'll like to be sure that i have the correct way of doing it.
Could it be ?

> CATALINA_OPTS -Duser.timezone=Asia/china

thanks for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "=" sign is specific to a particular application's syntax. For example bash uses "key=value", whereas, [launchctl](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/launchctl) uses a syntax similar to csh, "setenv key value".

[launchd.conf](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/launchd.conf.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/launchd.conf) (`$HOME/.launchd.conf` and `/etc/launchd.conf`) is a script of [launchctl](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/launchctl.1.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/1/launchctl) commands.

So in the case `CATALINA_OPTS=-Duser.timezone=Asia/china`, the key (often called the environment variable, env var, or just variable) is `CATALINA_OPTS` and the value is `-Duser.timezone=Asia/china`.

I know this for a few reasons.

- Typically, the environment variable name is all uppercase.
- The environment variable name appears before the first equals "=" (or space " ").
- The `-D` denotes the definition of a system property for [Java's VM](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html).

  - Note the key/value syntax for Java's system properties uses the "key=value" syntax.
  - Java system properties often contain a dot ".". Environment variable names don't.
  - So the key is `user.timezone` and the value is `Asia/china`.

An aside, I'm not sure `Asia/china` is a valid timezone. At least not according to the [list i found](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v5r3/index.jsp?topic=/rzatz/51/admin/reftz.htm). But maybe it'll work since China has a single timezone.